# How to display an image in Image Control as soon i browse?

Tags: asp.net

My Scenario,

Im using asp.net in vb. 
 I need to see the image in Image control as soon as i browse.and when i submit and it has to locate to the folder in server side.Is it possible through javascript.Please guide me.

Comment: Check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/04/03/image-preview-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. In the Onchange event of fileuploader make the src of  the path in the fileuploader and on update button click by using server.mappath u can save the image in a folder in server side.Bellow is the code call on onchange event of file uploader by passing this.value

```
  function Show(cntrl) {
     document.getElementById("Image1").src = cntrl;
     alert(document.getElementById("Image1").src);    
    return false;
 }
```